# Finding equation of tangent of a circle that intersects the origin?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

Given: circle with equation $(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=4$. How to find equation of tangent line to the circle that intersects the origin?

I easily found out that one of the tangents is $x=0$.

Comment: To find the other tangent that passes through the origin, you can let $y=mx$ be its equation and then find the value of $m$ for which this line intersects the circle exactly once (by setting $D=b^2-4ac=0$).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly one tangent is $x=0$, as you say. Reflect it in the line $y=x/2$ which passes through the origin and the centre of the circle and you get $y=-3x/4$ as the other tangent.